# SAS-calculating the percentage of variables

Tags: sas, calculation

Supposing a dataset as following:

```
firm_name      year  gender
A              2011     M
A              2011     M
A              2011     F
A              2012     M
A              2012     M
A              2012     F
A              2012     M
```

I use following code to do calculation.

```
proc sql;
    create table result as
    select firm_name,
            year,
            sum(case when(gender="M") then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as des
    from Have
    group by 1,2;
quit;
```

Comment: You should at least provide some attempt you've made to research and code this.  Have you looked at `proc freq` which will calculate this percentage by default?

Answer (score 0):

Longfish is correct. This can be implemented with *Proc freq*

```
data begin;
    input firm_name $ year  gender $ ;
    datalines;
    A 2011 M
    A 2011     M
    A 2011     F
    A 2012     M
    A 2012     M
    A 2012     F
    A 2012     M
    ;
run;
```

In SAS we always need to sort the data out. You can try to mess with the order and results are often interesting. Note that SAS process usually gives only warning, not errors.

```
proc sort data= begin; by firm_name year gender; run;

proc freq data= begin ; /*YOu can add noprint option in case of large files*/
    by firm_name year;
    table gender /out= wanted;
run;
```

For more on *proc Freq* see https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_sect006.htm